# Dependency resolver in .net

Tags: asp.net, dependencies, .net-assembly

I have 5 projects in my solution:

1. Project A
2. Project B
3. Project C
4. Project D
5. Project E

`Project A` is the starting point of my application.

Now let's take a look at how these projects reference each other.

- A references B
- B references C, D
- D references C, E

Let us remember that project "A" is the entry point in which calls into a function in "B" in which calls into a function in "C".

Project C tries to dynamically load the assembly "D" (D.dll exists in the bin folder of project "A" because of the reference of "B" to "D") by calling:

```
asm = Reflection.Assembly.Load("D")
someType = asm.GetType(asm.ToString.Substring(0, asm.ToString.IndexOf(",")) + "." + "SomeType")
```

This loads "D.dll" into memory BUT does NOT load the dependencies of project "D" for instance Project "E" which makes someType `null`.

However if we add a reference to "D" in project "A" (this is the only change) then everything works like a charm and all dependencies of Project "D" are loaded on demand.

What I want to know is that why the second scenario works but the first one doesn't?

Thanks for your time!